# $_FILES array showing up empty

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I have been trying to find a thread that could help, and have tried everything I could find to fix this.

I have a page that uploads a file, can be any type, and it works. I decided to use that same functionality on another page, but the $_FILES array is always empty.

Form:

```
 <form method="post" class="mainForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <fieldset>
        <div class="widget first">
           <div class="rowElem">
               <label for="file">Upload Profile Picture</label>
               <div class="formRight">
                   <input type="file" id="profilepicture" name="profilepicture" />
                   <button formaction="profile_pic.php"  class="greyishBtn">Upload</button>
               </div>
           </div>
      </fieldset>
  </form>
```

PHP:

```
$name_first = "John";
$name_last = "Doe";
$folder_name = $name_last . "-" . $name_first . "-ID-" . $id . "/";

$dirname = "profile/" . $folder_name;
if(!is_dir($dirname)){
    mkdir($dirname);
}

$dirname = $dirname .  $_FILES['file']['name'];

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $dirname)){
    header("location:profile.php");
}
else{
    echo $dirname; 
} 

?>
```

The `echo $dirname` just shows the folder with no file name.

Comment: There are two ways to submit the form, one is using `<form action="**">` the other is having it in the button. Through most of my site, I'm using the button tag instead of the `<input type="submit">` and have styled the button tags a certain way.

Comment: This `<button formaction` is invalid. At the least put a space between `form` and `action`.

Comment: `<form action="**">`.... really? Well I learned something new today, in my 15 years with working with forms, wow. Pardon the sarcasm, but you're wrong there Jack. There are many ways of submitting a form, and what you said, is NOT one of them, I can guarantee you that. Do what you want, hope it works. How, I have no idea. Good luck.

Comment: It is not invalid, and there is not space between it. validator.w3c.org did not show any errors. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad you have such extensive experience Fred, but regardless of what you say, the form submits using that.

Comment: Oh, and you may have misunderstood something. When I said `<form action="**">` I meant the ** to be like wildcards, in other words `<form action="somepage.php">`

Comment: Here is a useful link about `<button formaction="page.php">` http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fs-formaction

Comment: Ok Jack, I've found some documentation on it, and you're right **"to a certain extent"**, I'll give you that, but that won't guarantee that your form will work cross-platform/cross-browser. `<button formaction` is exclusive to HTML5. Browsers that are not HTML5 compatible will fail to execute the action. Why not just use one that will work for all and not just HTML5? Take my word for it, you'll eventually end up receiving emails from people saying that, they're unable to upload files. Or, they won't even bother and move on to another web site. This, by "experience". Do what you want Jack.

Comment: Thanks for the link Jack, that is the one I was reading actually, but appreciated nonetheless.

Comment: Because it is cross browser my friend. You know as well as I do that *most* of the HTML5 spec is cross browser for all but IE, and fortunately, this works on IE, and has been tested as far back as 7, even though 7 is on it's way out. (or is out depending on who you ask. 7 still has a 1.8% market share on one site I manage.)

Comment: If it works, great, I wish you well and trouble free. +1 for you on that. I said this, because I have many clients who still use non-HTML5 browsers, so I can do without them calling me and screaming at me etc. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your input file is called `name='profilepicture'`

Try:

```
$dirname = $dirname .  $_FILES['profilepicture']['name'];
```

and

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profilepicture']['tmp_name'], $dirname)){
 header("location:profile.php"); }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
$name_first = "John";
$name_last = "Doe";
$folder_name = $name_last . "-" . $name_first . "-ID-" . $id . "/";

$dirname = "profile/" . $folder_name;
if(!is_dir($dirname)){
    mkdir($dirname);
}

$dirname = $dirname .  $_FILES['profilepicture']['name'];

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profilepicture']['tmp_name'], $dirname)){
    header("location:profile.php");
}
else{
    echo $dirname; 
}
```

Comment: What's different with this?

Comment: Explanation to the OP for changes/modifications? Would help for the OP to know and why the code didn't work in the first place (wink)

Comment: I already knew why he said that as soon as I saw it. Didn't think about that, but it made sense as soon as I saw it.